# Is their a way to claim a pre-sales token using different wallet from the one used when buying it during pre-sales?

Tags: etherscan, presale

I am a crypto newbie, and participated in a pre-sales. However, the Zengo wallet I used when buying pre-sales token does not support the token. Is their a way to recover the token I bought. I did not attempt to claim the token as I am afraid the token will be lost for good.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you or

Comment: What do you mean with "pre-sales token"? Does that wallet generated a mnemonic passphrase?